# Check whether is it possible to divide array into 2 subsets of sum atleast k?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, optimization

Given an array of the size of n, we have to check whether is it possible to divide the elements of Array into two subsets such that the sum of both the subsets is at least k.
How can I approach this problem?

**My Approach:**

I thought of a Greedy Approach to take all the bigger elements till it reaches k and check if `total_sum-sum>=k`. But this logic is not correct.

Another approach I thought was to brute force, simply recurse all possible subsets and find whether it's satisfying my condition. But it's the time complexity is exponential, even after using DP it's of `O(n^2)`

but `2<=n<=2*10^5`.

Can you please help me to find an optimal approach to this problem?

Comment: How is "2<=n<=2*10^5" relevant?

Comment: @ScottHunter, that tells us that probably the solution algorithm should have complexity lower than O(n^2)

Comment: Straightforward variant of the subset sum DP.

Comment: I tried the DP approach but it gave TLE on some test cases so I was wondering if there is  another approach (maybe some sort of Greedy) with lower time Complexity, less than O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

## This is not possible

If we take `k` to be half of the sum of the whole array, then the problem is known as the [Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is famously **NP**-complete. There is no known algorithm that can consistently (in reasonable time) solve any **NP**-complete problem for `n=2*10^5`.

P.S. note that the brute force solution runs in `O(2^n)`, not `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Well, even Knapsack is NP-complete but there is a dynamic programming algorithm with pseudo-polynomial time complexity for it. NP-complete ≠ no algorithm exists.

Comment: @abc Indeed, partition is pseudopolynomial as well. However, no bounds were given on the value of the input, only the size, so I think my point stands. I certainly never claimed that there is no algorithm that solves **NP**-complete problems.